# Is there a smarter (way to) npm?

Tags: node.js, npm

As far as I know `npm` resolves module dependencies by allowing each module to require everything as a tree. This means that if `module1` uses `dependency1-v1.0`, and `module2` also uses this same dependency, they'll both download it, so we'd have a file structure like this:

```
/node_modules
    /module1
        /node_modules
            /dependency1-v1.0
            /dependency2-v0.9
    /module2
        /node_modules
            /dependency1-v1.0
            /dependency2-v0.9
    /module3
        /node_modules
            /dependency1-v1.2
            /dependency2-v0.9
```

Is there a node package manager which is smart enough to realize this and manage the dependencies in a common collection, which could look something like this?

```
/packages
    /module1
    /module2
    /module3
/dependencies
    /dependency1
        /v1.0
        /v1.2
    /dependency2
        /v0.9
```

It would be nice if it could perform garbage collection and remove unreferenced/unused dependencies, preferably automatically (e.g. `npm rm`).

Another thing I often see is that modules have tests and dev-dependencies which are only useful if one wants to make sure if a module is performing as expected, but I think usually this just wastes space, time and bandwidth.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to install node modules without having to have all these bloats?

## Clarification

Yes, I'm aware that in modules one would just probably do something like this to load a dependency:

```
var dep1 = require('dependency1');
```

instead of also specifying its version here, which is defined in the `package.json`. However, I still think it should be possible to instead of just downloading everything into the module's own node_modules directory, this could be resolved either with symlinks or simple "facade" loader files which would be managed by the "smarter npm".

Comment: for websites use bower. otherwise it doesn't really matter, the files are small anyway.

Comment: *"Another thing I often see is that modules have tests and dev-dependencies which are only useful if one wants to make sure if a module is performing as expected, but I think usually this just wastes space, time and bandwidth."* and they of course only install if your node env is dev.

Comment: @KevinB sure, while I'm developing my *own* thing, the environment would be dev, but do I really care about the dev dependencies of 3rd party modules? Hardly.

Comment: Write your own package manager.

Comment: @KevinB Perhaps I don't have to. Perhaps others have already figured this out. That's exactly why I have posted this question. :)

Comment: The updates in @3 actually appear to solve your concerns directly. Try installing the beta to see for yourself.

Answer (score 4):

From the [FAQ](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/faq#why-can-t-npm-just-put-everything-in-one-place-like-other-package-managers):

> **Why can't npm just put everything in one place, like other package
>   managers?**
>
> Not every change is an improvement, but every improvement is a change.
>   This would be like asking git to do network IO for every commit. It's
>   not going to happen, because it's a terrible idea that causes more
>   problems than it solves.
>
> **It is much harder to avoid dependency conflicts without nesting
>   dependencies. This is fundamental to the way that npm works, and has
>   proven to be an extremely successful approach. See npm-folders(5) for
>   more details.**
>
> If you want a package to be installed in one place, and have all your
>   programs reference the same copy of it, then use the npm link command.
>   That's what it's for. Install it globally, then link it into each
>   program that uses it.

.

> **Whatever, I really want the old style 'everything global' style.**
>
> Write your own package manager. You could probably even wrap up npm in
>   a shell script if you really wanted to.
>
> npm will not help you do something that is known to be a bad idea.

---

If even after all of that you still want this feature, go to the npm git and submit a feature request, SO isn't the place for npm feature requests.

[Though, it seems we may be seeing some improvements to this in npm@3](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v3.0.0):

> Your dependencies will now be installed maximally flat. Insofar as is possible, all of your dependencies, and their dependencies, and THEIR dependencies will be installed in your project's node_modules folder with no nesting. You'll only see modules nested underneath one another when two (or more) modules have conflicting dependencies.

Comment: I find it humorous that the change they're making in @3 was considered to be a known bad idea previously by npm.